# Trouble scraping email information from a website

Tags: python, php, beautifulsoup, tesseract

I wish to get persmission to use the images on [www.confluence.org](http://www.confluence.org) for an art project but i need to do that by going to each individual member and asking for thier permission. There is about 10,000 people on the site.

I want to use BeautifulSoup to scrape the site for all the emails, so i can send one mass email instead of 1 email 10,000 times.

The problem however is the email is not written into the the html using text, but what i assume is a php file....located inside an img src.

```html
<img src="visitormailimg.php?id=851" border="0" alt>
```

and an example of how this appears on the site is    [image]

I initially thought of the above email as a simple image that I could run through tesseract to get  the text version of the email, but tesseract doesn't recognize it as an image object. I can click and download the php file as an image manually, but i cant figure out how to do something similar when scraping

Then i saved the webpage onto a folder on my desktop and opened the saved php file visitormailimg.php. Except when opened it i get "*the file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses unsupported text encode*" in vscode.

So i am at this stage unsure of how to proceed scraping ww.confluence.org website. Is it an image problem...is it a php problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: `opened the saved php file visitormailimg.php. Except when i do this i get "the file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses unsupported text encode`...yeah because it's actually an image, not a PHP text file. PHP was used to return the image data, but saving it with a PHP extension is misleading. The headers in the network tool of your browser when you load that page should contain the mime type showing what type of image it actually is.

Comment: As for scraping, your scraping tool would need to make a HTTP request to that URL separately, download the data, and then pass it to the image recognition software.

Comment: Thanks man. Ill work on it. Cheers for the quick response

Comment: Isn't it almost as if they don't want member's email addresses to be scraped?